problems with updating database
I have some code to update a table:
$updateLastAttempt = new stdClass();
$tempDate = new DateTime('now');
$formattedDate = $tempDate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$updateLastAttempt->id = $pxobjUpdate->id;
$updateLastAttempt->last_attempted_sms = "" . $formattedDate . "";
array_push($uniqueIdArray,$pxuniqueid);
array_push($recallRecordIdArray,$recallRecordid);

if ($debug != 1) {
    echo"<br>Update last attempt date to:".$formattedDate." for id:".$pxuniqueid. " recall Record id:".$recallRecordid;
    $db = JFactory::getDbo();

    $query = $db->getQuery(true);

    $fields = array(
        $db->quoteName('last_attempted_sms') . ' = "' . $formattedDate.'"',
    );

    $conditions = array(
        $db->quoteName('id') . ' = "'.$pxobjUpdate->id.'"',
    );

    $query->update($db->quoteName('#__patientrecalls_px_record'))->set($fields)->where($conditions);

    $db->setQuery($query);

    $result = $db->execute();
}

Originally I used an object and did an update that way but I was getting errors so I switched to this proceedural method.  It's a joomla 3 site (I know it should be updated).
The problem I'm having is that not all of the records are updating.  It seems to just ignore the update for a random number of records.  It updates most of them but not all of them and I can't see anything that might cause this.  It's just a straight up record update by using the id .
any ideas??

If the process is only working sometimes, then you don't have a coding problem, you have a data problem.  We cannot help you without better debilugging details.  Perhaps try to implement the Debugging techniques at Correct ways to verify update query is successful under conditions then [edit] your question to clarify the problem.

What kind of insights can you derive from this script? https://3v4l.org/EcbLf

Put a try...catch around the $db->execute() and see if the query is failing for the records that don't get updated (use $query->dump() to get the full query string).
If not then it must be that whatever you are using above this to select the $pxobjUpdate objects is missing some.
Not sure what all of the stuff at the top before the if (debug) is doing for you. Is this all in a loop iterating over the $pxobjUpdate objects or a function that is passed a single $pxobjUpdate object to update?

My guess that the ID ($pxobjUpdate->id) is sometimes passed as empty (which could mean that the object in itself is empty). In addition, by quickly glancing at your code, I see that you have about 3 variables storing the ID, which is not good practice. One other reason is that the code might be failing at one point.
